How to use verify domain usernames in PowerShell for Local Groups & Users
This script will be used for an upcoming device refresh to add users to the local Administrators group
$User = $env:USERNAME # Retrieves the current user's name
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $User 

This will be used on a domain with hundreds of users, and I want the script to verify the usernames in AD (similar to the Check Names button in AD Users and Comptuers) to verify the user's info.
How can I do this?

May I ask why your company decided to do the absolute batsh*t crazy thing of giving administrator rights to every single user on the computer they use? That sounds like a ticking bomb that will blow up in the IT Department's face.
Beyond that, how exactly your company domain work in this case? I mean it seems you have both local users logged in into the computers, AND a domain where the users have exactly the same username. What's the point of such a hybrid system? Why don't you join all the computers to the AD, and manage the individual user rights for PCs through group policies in the AD?

You'll need to go completely back to the drawing board on this.
Validating a username with AD is easy (see: Get-ADUser), but your script needs administrator privileges in order to add users to the group. If the user in $env:USERNAME doesn't already have this access, you won't be able to do it, and if they do they're already in the group, so it's not needed.
So you need to run the script with elevated permissions, via "Run as Administrator" or similar, so a non-privileged user can edit the group membership. But this requires credentials or an existing token for a different user that already has the access. And now the problem is the script will then run in that user's context, with the wrong value for $env:USERNAME. There's really no way to avoid this. So: back to the drawing board.

But most of all, this seems like a really bad idea from a security perspective. If your environment is big enough you have deployment tools for running this kind of script in bulk or for targeted stations remotely, you should be using those tools to help users do things they may otherwise need to use administrator privileges to accomplish in the first place.
I have seen smaller organizations grant admin rights to individual users on the one machine assigned directly to them. This works in organizations up to about 100 or so employees, where the IT environment hasn't scaled enough yet to support more detailed controls. But at any larger scale this is asking for disaster.
Incidentally, this describes my current situation: just less than 100 FTE, but only two IT staff responsible for servers, PCs, wifi, email, applications, phones, printing, reporting, you name it. But we still don't give out admin rights by default; users have to ask first. Even then we may push back, and we don't give it out just because; you need to have a reason involving something more than we could do for you in a few minutes. We also have controls, among which are documentation for admin grants and auditing UAC remains turned on (so users are never admin-by-default).

If you really need to push forward with this (and remember: I said, "If"), you'll want to create a mapping of computer to username that is accessible to your script. Have the script run elevated from an account with administrator credentials, check what computer it's running on, and then check the mapping to know what username to add to the group.

This is indeed the correct response. From the hip my general recommendation for automating this type of analysis at scale would be to 1) audit all DC's for event ID 4624, 2) use those events to map usernames -> workstations, 3) periodically manually verify/approve which ones go on to get local admin membership on the mapped endpoints, and then 4) leave local group membership modification as a task for a trusted management agent (eg. Intune or SMS agent) on the device

"I’m aware of the massive security risk and have informed the client many times, but it’s falling on deaf ears. This isn't the full script due to sensitive information. I’m just looking for a way to use the 'Check Names' button to auto-fill the user’s email in 'Select Users, Computers, Service Accounts, Groups".

@ItsTriich You will not be able to use that button. You'll have to settle for doing a similar check on your own... which again, Get-ADUser can do. If it returns a result, you have a match. But as I said: it won't help you on it's own, since you need elevation to complete this, and once you elevate the username will have changed.
